# Route not defined error in laravel , even though route is defined

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I have the followning method in my controller:

```
public function showQualityResult($qualityData) {
        return $qualityData;
}
```

When clicked on a link , i want that method to be invoked , so i have the following in my view file:

```
<a href="{{ route('showQualityResult' , Session::get('quality-data')) }}">Submited Quality Check</a>
```

Also, I have the following route setup:

```
Route::get('/showQualityResult', 'QualityCheckController@showQualityResult');
```

But having the below line of code:

```
<a href="{{ route('showQualityResult' , Session::get('quality-data')) }}">Submited Quality Check</a>
```

Does't really work , i get the following error in the frontEnd:

[image]

Now how can i solve this problem , and why am i getting this error of Route not defined , even though i have the route defined ??

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[`route()`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/helpers#method-route) helper uses route name to build URL, so you need to use it like this:

```
route('quality-result.show', session('quality-data'));
```

And set a name for the route:

```
Route::get('/showQualityResult', ['as' => 'quality-result.show', 'uses' => 'QualityCheckController@showQualityResult']);
```

Or:

```
Route::get('/showQualityResult', 'QualityCheckController@showQualityResult')->name('quality-result.show');
```

> The route function generates a URL for the given named route

https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/routing#named-routes

If you don't want to use route names, use [`url()`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/helpers#method-url) instead of [`route()`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/helpers#method-route)

Comment: thanks ... but with the `url()` method i can't pass parameters right ?

Comment: @AlexanderSolonik it can, you can see an example by clicking `url()` link in my answer. Another thing is you're using session to store the data. In this case you don't need to pass it anywhere. You can just get it with `session('quality-data')` in a controller method.

Answer (score 2):

The `route()` helper looks for a named route, not the path.

https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/routing#named-routes

```
Route::get('/showQualityResult', 'QualityCheckController@showQualityResult')
    ->name('showQualityResult');
```

Should fix the issue for you.

Answer (score 0):

In my case I had simply made a stupid mistake.

Further down in my code I had another named route (properly named with a unique name) but an identical path to the one Laravel told me it couldn't find.

A quick update to the path fixed it.